# Can someone explain to me what are these 2 statements talking about?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to prove that these 2 statements are equivalent, but I can't even understand them.

1. There exist $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $k\in\mathbb N$, there exist $n_k\in\mathbb N$ such that $n_k\geq k$ and $|x_{n_k}-x|\geq\epsilon_0$?
2. There exist $\epsilon_0>0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of sequence $(x_n)$ such that $|x_{n_k}-x|\geq\epsilon_0$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Thank you.

Comment: Answers are likely to be more useful and concise and less work for the answerer if you point out which parts of the statements you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an exercise to get you thinking about the logic of these kinds of statements, and to get used to reading them - you are likely to encounter many more of similar form. It is therefore worth putting in some effort to decode them. Sometimes it is easiest to work from the end, because this is the target statement, and the rest is needed to frame it accurately in context.

So in the first one, this is aiming at $|x_{n_k}-x|\geq\epsilon_0$, which we can interpret as $x_{n_k}$ is not close to $x$ - so we are trying to find terms of the sequence which are further away from $x$ than $\epsilon_0$.

We are indexing these terms with positive integers $n_k$, and we want an infinite number of them. We could do that in different ways - here it is done by setting $n_k \ge k$, so we can't choose $n_k=1$ every time, because the sequence eventually has to grow.

This is an interesting way of doing it, because it doesn't specify that the $n_k$ are growing all the time, rather it says that they eventually get bigger than any definite integer. So the sequence $n_k$ could begin $10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6 \dots$ but by the time we reach $n_{11}$ the value has to be at least 11.

Note that this example does not give you a subsequence, but you should be able to show that a subsequence does satisfy the condition $n_k \ge k$, hence that a subsequence defined as in $2$  - which we can see is also looking for elements of the original sequence which are not close to $x$ - satisfies all the conditions of definition 1.

The real work is showing that you can pick an increasing sequence of integers from the $n_k$ in definition 1, which will index your subsequence. You will need to use the observation that the $n_k$ grow eventually. One approach is to assume you have picked the first $r$ numbers and  to show that you can then pick the $(r+1)th$.

Answer (score 2):

They both say

> There are infinitely many $n$, such that $x_n$ is not an element of $(x-\epsilon_0, x + \epsilon_0)$, that is $I := \{n \in \mathbb N \mid x_n \not\in (x - \epsilon_0, x + \epsilon_0)\}$ is infinite.

In the first formulation, the point that $I$ is infinite is formulated as $I$ being unbounded in $\mathbb N$, that is for each $k$ there is some element (called $n_k$) of $I$ being larger than $k$. In the second one, the point is that with $I$ being infinite, we can write $I = \{n_1, n_2, \ldots\}$, $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ and obtain a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ by using the elements of $I$ as indices.

Answer (score 1):

We have a sequence $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of real numbers. (1) and (2) are both statements about that sequence. The second is a little simpler, so I’ll start with it.

(2) says that there is some positive distance $\epsilon_0$ such that a whole subsequence of $\sigma$ consists of terms that are at least $\epsilon_0$ units away from the number $x$. That is, there is an increasing sequence $n_0<n_1<n_2<\ldots$ of natural numbers such that every one of the terms $x_{n_k}$ of the original sequence $\sigma$ is at least $\epsilon_0$ units distant from the number $x$. Equivalently, each of these terms $x_{n_k}$ lies outside the open interval $(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$. We might say that $\sigma$ has a subsequence whose terms are *bounded away from* $x$ by a distance $\epsilon_0$. (You should note, by the way, that this just says that infinitely many terms of $\sigma$ are outside the interval $(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$: once you have infinitely many such terms, you can certainly list them in order of increasing subscripts to get a subsequence of $\sigma$.)

(1) also says that there is a positive distance $\epsilon_0$ such that certain terms of the sequence $\sigma$ are at least $\epsilon_0$ units distance from $x$, i.e, outside the open interval $(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$. Specifically, there is a function $\varphi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that for each $k\in\Bbb N$, $\varphi(k)\ge k$ **and** the point $x_{\varphi(k)}$ is at least $\epsilon_0$ units distant from $x$, i.e., not in the open interval $(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$.

> The problem statement uses the notation $n_k$ for this integer that I’ve called $\varphi(k)$, but that’s potentially confusing, since it makes $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, my $\langle x_{\varphi(k)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, look like a subsequence of $\sigma$, which it technically is not, since the sequence of indices $\langle n_0,n_1,n_2,\dots\rangle$, or in my notation $\langle\varphi(0),\varphi(1),\varphi(2),\dots\rangle$, need not be increasing.

---

Proving that (2) implies (1) is fairly straightforward, once you notice that if $\langle n_0,n_1,n_2,\dots\rangle$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers, then $n_k\ge k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. This is easily proved by induction on $k$.

Proving that (1) implies (2) is a little harder. You’ll want to assume that you have an $\epsilon_0$ and a function $\varphi$ as in (my version of) (1), and use them to construct a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of $\sigma$ as in (2). This construction will be recursive. You can start by letting $n_0=\varphi(0)$: then $n_0\ge 0$ (which of course it was bound to be anyway!), and $x_{n_0}\notin(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$. Now you need an $n_1$ such that $n_1>n_0$ and $x_{n_1}\notin(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$. Any $\varphi(k)$ has the property that $x_{\varphi(k)}\notin(x-\epsilon_0,x+\epsilon_0)$, so we could get the desired separation of $x_{n_1}$ from $x$ with any $x_{\varphi(k)}$, but we also want $n_1=\varphi(k)>n_0$. This is easily managed when we recall that $\varphi(k)\ge k$ for every $k\in\Bbb N$: just let $n_1=\varphi(n_0+1)$. All that remains is to generalize this to explain how to get $n_{k+1}$ once you have $n_k$.